Не запускается код на ESP32
При попытке запустить код, он компилируется и всё хорошо. Однако в условном операторе функция pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat() не возвращает true (хотя должна), тем самым не запускает измерение пульса.
Все соединения и прочую аппаратную часть полностью проверил, всё верно. Проблема именно в программной части.
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>

const char* ssid = "YourWiFiSSID";
const char* password = "YourWiFiPassword";
const char* serverAddress = "http://192.168.0.3:5000/api/heartbeat"; // Замените на адрес вашего сервера

const int PulseWire = 0; // Подключите PulseSensor к аналоговому пину 0
const int LED = LED_BUILTIN;
int Threshold = 550;

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  connectToWiFi();

  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED);
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);

  if (pulseSensor.begin()) {
    Serial.println("PulseSensor object created successfully!");
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) {
    int bpm = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();

    Serial.print("BPM: ");
    Serial.println(bpm);

    sendDataToServer(bpm);
  }

  delay(20);
}

void connectToWiFi() {
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void sendDataToServer(int bpm) {
  HTTPClient http;

  String jsonData = "{\"bpm\": " + String(bpm) + "}";

  Serial.print("Sending data to server...");
  if (http.begin(serverAddress)) {
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(jsonData);

    if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
      Serial.printf("HTTP Response code: %d\n", httpResponseCode);
      String response = http.getString();
      Serial.println(response);
    } else {
      Serial.printf("Error sending POST request! HTTP Error code: %d\n", httpResponseCode);
    }

    http.end();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unable to connect to server!");
  }
}
 


Попробуйте поиграться со значением Threshold
